# Magento Event Observers or Custom Modules Not Working On Production

Tags: php, magento, observers

I'm attempting to use multiple observer classes & modules for Magento, all of which are being put into app/code/local. These all work on my local workstation, but will NOT work when I copy them to production via FTP. I am going crazy trying to figure out what's going on. All of my code seems sound. Here's an example of an observer:

app/code/local/Mural/Pricing/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php 
class Mural_Pricing_Model_Observer {
    public function setMuralPricing($observer) {
        echo 'We did it!';
        die();
    } 
}
```

app/code/local/Mural/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mural_Pricing>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Mural_Pricing>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Mural_Pricing>
                <class>Mural_Pricing_Model</class>
            </Mural_Pricing>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <sales_quote_add_item>
                <observers>
                    <Mural_Pricing>
                        <class>mural_pricing/observer</class>
                        <method>setMuralPricing</method>
                    </Mural_Pricing>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_add_item>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

app/etc/modules/Mural_Pricing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mural_Pricing>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Mural_Pricing>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Like I said, this works fine locally, but not in production, with several different observers & modules. Frustrating. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice is that your observer declaration is to call `mural_pricing/observer::setMuralPricing()` on your observed event.

If you look at the config XML, you're registering models in this module as `Mural_Pricing/...` as per this XML:

```
<models>
    <Mural_Pricing>
        <class>Mural_Pricing_Model</class>
    </Mural_Pricing>
</models>
```

Magento best practice seems to be to use all lowercase for class aliases, so I suggest you change that to `mural_pricing`. It will also work if you change your observer declaration to use the uppercased equivalent.

On another point, I don't think it actually matters what you name this tag, but the `<Mural_Pricing>` tag underneath `<observers>` should ideally represent a short description of what your observer does (again, don't think it *actually* matters) - e.g. `<mural_pricing_set_pricing>`.

Finally, it has to be said - ensure that you've cleared your cache correctly to re-parse the XML configuration. If you're using Redis or another caching architecture in production vs dev/staging/local then you may have forgotten to clear your cache a different way to how you do it locally.

Ultimately, your module looks fine other than the case difference in the class alias and observer declaration.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I wasn't able to make this work even after implementing your suggestions, but useful advice regardless.